# bootstrap Flex box not working on ngb-rating rating

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to align items of the flex at the center using ngb-rating but the bootstrap styles are not applying.

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
  <h3>Team Lead</h3>
  <div class="rating-number d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <p>4.5</p>
    <ngb-rating class="black-star" [(rate)]="this.star" [readonly]="true" max="1"></ngb-rating>
  </div>
</div>
```

`.black-star { color: #000000; }`

I am trying to make it look this way:

[image: style for star rating]

Comment: Try to create a [working snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, just checking with the "!important" rule might be to override your CSS, or you can create a demo in stackblitz and share the link here. Apply as below
.black-star { color: #000 !important}

Note: Use "!important" is just for a debug purpose.